# Can I use firestore and GCP identity platform with multiple domains?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-identity

We have been developing a SaaS for a while.

We decided to use [Google Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform) to handle [multi-tenant authentication](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-quickstart), and [firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore) as our main database, but I have some doubts.

Can I use Identity Platform with multiple domains and subdomains?

This question comes to mind because in the application I will allow my clients to connect their custom domain in addition to a free subdomain, for example:

Client1 will have
client1.com and client1.myapp.com

Client2 will have client2.com and client2.myapp.com

However, I would like to know if I can use the identity platform in that way and if it is possible.

I would also like to know if it is possible to perform the same task but with firestore, so that my clients can obtain data from a single firestore database from multiple domains and subdomains.

It should be noted that we already have the mechanism configured to host multiple domains on our custom servers, we simply want to integrate firestore and identity platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure an authorised domain for each tenant in GCIP.  There are a few ways to manage multiple tenants / domains in Cloud Firestore.

### Add a root level domains collection

Split your data at the root level.  This will mean that you will have multiple versions of your sub-collections, which isn't an issue if you are querying entirely within a domain / tenant.  However, you can use collectionGroup queries to get around this.

```
domains / client1 / users  / user123
                  / mydata / mydata1
domains / client2 / users  / user456
                  / mydata / mydata2
```

### Specify the domain in each document

You can stick with a conventional collection structure and add the domain to each document.  With this option, bear in mind that each query will require an index in order to allow for your `domainId` field.

```
/ users  / user123
/ users  / user456
/ mydata / mydata1
/ mydata / mydata1
```

Each document will need a `domainId` field for you to filter.

```
{
  displayName: 'Bob Smaith',
  domainId: 'client1'
}
```